# Computing shortest paths with networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have an edgelist (node1 node2 weight).  Attempting to identify the weighted shortest path lengths among all nodes.  Here is my data: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DxSL5lSgsHYdR7kWmauVWA7CW_Q05xPS/view?usp=sharing

Can't get it to produce output.

Not sure if I am reading in the weights correctly or including them in the shortest path production.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.read_weighted_edgelist
(r'C:\Users\james\Desktop\Documents\Downloads\\bpAFTSi.pr',create_using= 
nx.DiGraph())  

G=nx.path_graph(48)
len_path = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra(G))
print(len_path[3][0][1])

for node in G:
    print('3 - {}: {}'.format(node, len_path[3][0][node]))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Can't get it to produce output"?  Is it just not finishing the calculation?

Comment: When I run the last cell of code, nothing happens.  No error message.  Just sits there.  I see that correct data has been read in and the G graph created.

Comment: At first I was running with a much larger file and I thought it was just a long run time.  So, I changed to a file with only 48 nodes.

Comment: The code runs for me (using the path graph, once I indent the final print statement).

Comment: I had it indented.  Did not indent in this post.  Hmm...it doesn't run for me.

Comment: I am going to reboot and try again.

Comment: Runs for me. Takes virtually 0 time.

Comment: The earlier attempt with the large file apparently generated a memory fault.  After rebooting, the code runs.  But, looking at the output, I don't see that the shortest paths incorporate the edge weights.  Looking at the output the shortest path values seem anomalous.  The look mostly like consecutive numbers.  Can you see why this is happening?

Comment: The shortest paths in the output are ordered by their lengths, that is why they look like sequential numbers. If you compare the outputs for the graph from your file and for the synthetic unweighted graph, they are very different. So, the weights are definitely taken into account.

Comment: My next step is to generate an output file containing the path values for all pairs of nodes.

Comment: What I want to do is write to a file, for each pair of nodes, the strength value for the shortest path.  How would I do this?

Comment: I tried this:  print(node,len_path) and got output I can't make sense of.   0 {0: ({0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47}, ...  Looking for path lengths.

Comment: The first `0` is `node`.  The rest is `len_path`.  The first part shows you the lengths from `0`  The length from `0` to `0` in your unweighted path is `0`.  The length from `0` to `1` in the unweighted path is `1`.  The length from `0` to `2` is `2`, etc.  The part in `...` is probably {1:({0:1, 1:0, 2:1,...` meaning that the length of the path from `1` to `0` is `1`, from `1` to `1` is `0`, from `1` to `2` is `1` etc.  Try doing your last `for` loop, which will give the lengths from `3` to each node.

Comment: I am now trying to read in a edgelist file with float weights.  1  2 4.5,
1  4  3.4,
2  5  6.7,
4  5  6.0,
2  3  4.9      How do I read in the float values in networkx?   Data file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GvZRTcuD227tIg_Q4eKZ-yOO3bLl-wvg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also created a test file with weights in the hundreds so I could clearly see where in the output the strengths were reflected, which is as yet I don't see.  Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/125OVYNsGTYgnxs7HRv9Jg64bKfnn4m64/view?usp=sharing